# Application.Run - change use button click event

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I've a little problem concerns Application.Run method. It's possible to change Application.Run (in default Program.cs file) when I clicked button1 should change Application.Run line to eg.

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

then button2 was clicked

```
Application.Run(new Form2());
```

If above situations can we change when program is still running?

Thanks for advices!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Application.Run()` runs you're program's main message loop.
You cannot modify it once it starts.

Instead, you can simply `Show()` a new form instance, and perhaps `Hide()` the old one.